# value not getting passed through button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am very new to python language
Just wanted help on a python program, which I somehow managed to write after many hot and trial.

```
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import *

def qf(par):
    print(par)
class App:
    def __init_(self, master):
        frame = Frame(self, master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text='LED ON', command=self.convert0)
        self.button.grid(row=5, coloumnspan=5)
    def convert0(self, tog[0]):
        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            self.button.config(text='LED OFF')
        else:
            self.button.config(text='LED OFF'. command=lambda:qf("1!!!"))
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('LED Prog')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The output of program is when i click button with 'LED ON' it passes the value '1!!!' and button gets stuck at 'LED ON', doesnot changes to 'LED OFF'.

What I want is when button is 'LED ON' that time 1!!!! should display in output and when button is 'LED OFF' no value should display.

I know this might be a small code change for python expert, but need little help here.
also can anyone share some links for learning python.

Thanks in advance.
Pls dont block the question
I am using python 2.7.9

Comment: What is `tog`? `def convert0(self, tog[0]):` is definitely going to give you a syntax error. (So does the `:` after `frame = Frame(self, master)`. So does the `.` after `text='LED OFF'`)

Comment: Copy and paste the code you actually ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got what I was looking for hope this helps others also.

```
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import *

class App:

def __init__(self, master): 
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text='LED ON', command=self.convert0)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.LED = Label(frame).grid(row=2, column=1)

def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

    tog[0] = not tog[0]
    if tog[0]:
        print('1')
        self.button.config(text='LED OFF')
    else:
        self.button.config(text='LED ON')

root = Tk()

root.wm_title('LED on & off program')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This works perfectly as I wanted.

@WoLy thanks for your efforts, but I was looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `button.configure(text=)` to change text, to alternate between `OFF` and `ON` use a variable to save the state.

```
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import *


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text='LED ON', command=self.convert0)
        self.button.pack()
        self.state = 1

    def convert0(self):
        states = ['ON', 'OFF']
        self.state = not self.state
        # True == 1 and False == 0
        self.button.configure(text='LED {0}'.format(states[not self.state]))

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('LED Prog')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Use of `grid` method:

```
grid(row=, column=) then you can give `rowspan` or `columnspan`.
```

Comment: @shivam Is this useful?

Comment: Well actually when the button is "LED ON" and I click it some value like "ON" should pass through the button and displayed in output and status of Button change to "LED OFF", and when Button is "LED OFF" then no value should pass though it. Anyways thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: that's why I used "def qf(par)" to pass the value when I click the button in "LED ON" state

Answer (score 0):

This is, if I understood you well, what you are looking for:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ The constructor consists of a a root widget to which
        is attached one Button child widget.
        """
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.led = Button(frame, fg="red", text="Start",  width=15,command=self.button_state)
        self.led.pack() # Use pack() if no other widgets are planned to take place
    def button_state(self):
        """ Switch the button text from LED OFF to LED ON: 1
        At the start of the program, the button text is set to 'Start'.
        """
        if self.led["text"] == "LED OFF" or self.led["text"] == "Start":
            self.led["text"] ="LED ON: 1"
        else:
            self.led["text"]="LED OFF"


root = Tk()
root.wm_title('LED Prog')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Result:**

Clicking on the button will switch between these 2 states:

- [image]
- [image]